# My DialogBox get called many times when using livedata android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I am trying to show DialogBox when my response is received using repository -> ViewModel -> Livedata -> UI.
Basically I am using data flow from repository to viewModel to Ui using livedata.
But I am using Sealed class also in my ViewModel for managing Uistate.

Below is the code :

ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel(context: Context, private val repository: ProductRepository) : BaseViewModel<UiState>() {

private val networkLiveData: NetworkLiveData = NetworkLiveData(context)

fun observeNetworkConnectivity(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    networkLiveData.observe(owner) { isConnected ->
        if (isConnected == true) {
            // Perform network-related operations
            observer(isConnected)
        } else {
            // Handle no network connection
            if (isConnected != null) {
                observer(isConnected)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun callApi() {
    uiState.value = UiState.Loading

    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.getAPIResponse()
        uiState.value = UiState.Success(repository.productLD)
    }
}
fun sendPostAPI(addProductModel: AddProductModel) {

    uiState.value = UiState.Loading

    viewModelScope.launch {

        val response = repository.sendDataAPI(addProductModel)
        Log.d("ViewModel","viewmodel sendPostAPI is $response")
        uiState.value = UiState.Success(response)
    }

}



  }
```

BaseViewModel

```
 open class BaseViewModel<T> : ViewModel() {

       fun uiState(): LiveData<T> = uiState
       protected val uiState: MutableLiveData<T> = MutableLiveData()
    }
```

Fragment

```
   override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

  fragment_addProductBinding = FragmentAddProductBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        this, viewModelFactory
    ).get(MainViewModel::class.java)


    viewModel.observeNetworkConnectivity(viewLifecycleOwner) { isConnected ->
        internetState = isConnected
    }

    show() // triggered here

   }


  fun show(){
    if (internetState) {
                
                viewModel.sendPostAPI(addProductModel)

                viewModel.uiState().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {  // refer here line #23

                    Log.d("AddProduct","updated data is $it")

                    if (it != null) {
                        onSuccess(it)
                    }

                }

            } else {
                requireActivity().toast("Internet Connection Lost !!")

            }
        }
   
     private fun onSuccess(data: Any) = with(fragment_addProductBinding) {

    Log.d("AddProduct","updated data is Success ")

    fragment_addProductBinding.progressBarAddProduct.setGone()
    fragment_addProductBinding.backButton.isEnabled = true
    fragment_addProductBinding.submitButton.isEnabled = true
    backButton.setDefaultColor()
    submitButton.setDefaultColor()


        Log.d("AddProduct","updated data is modelclass $data ")

        data as ProductAddedSuccessfullyModel
        showDialogBoxOnSuccess(data)   // Dialog Box Here


    }

      private fun showDialogBoxOnSuccess(data: ProductAddedSuccessfullyModel) {

        val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Success !!")

        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(data.message)

        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ ->

            dialog.dismiss()
        }

        val alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create()
        alertDialog.show()

    }
```

Problem is :

My Dialog box for the first time appears for once but for 2 times it appear twice and 3 time 4-5 times .

I checked that it is due to the viewmodel.uiState().observe line #23.
I don't understand this behaviour .

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where show() is called from?

Comment: Hey, thanks buddy, I edited. Can you check again.